# How do I prefill the vim command line with a function and then edit the result?

Tags: command-line

Got this function:

```
function! TaskAnnotateWithFile()
    let uuid = GetUUID()
    :!task 
    echo uuid . ' '
    annotate -- ~/
endfunction
```

The idea here is a I want to prefill the command line with something like this:

`:task 693614b6-0141-4e22-93cd-ebc37ef47d55 annotate -- ~/`

I then want to be able to tab to the file I need with the prompt at the end of the command.

However, after the function runs, I get spilled back out into normal mode and I'm not in the command line. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: How do you call the function, from a mapping? If it's from a mapping, you might have some success using an `<expr>` mapping that will return the `:` Ex sequence not including a `<CR>` at the end that will allow for you to continue typing it... If it's not from a mapping, then maybe `feedkeys()` is what you need?

Comment: Yes, with a mapping. I'm not familiar with the <expr> mapping. I'll look it up. So that `<expr>` goes in the right hand side of the map?

Comment: @filbranden means something like `nnoremap <expr> <leader>X printf(':!task %s annotate -- ~/', GetUUID())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to trigger this with a mapping then there's really no need for the function. Everything can happen in the mapping without much trouble.

There are a couple ways to approach this.<sup>*</sup> I just happened to be using the [`c_CTRL-\_e`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-%5C_e) command-line editing feature recently  so let's use that. The key command looks like this:

```
CTRL-\ e {expr}
```

This populates the command line with whatever the expression in `{expr}` evaluates to. Our expression will be:

```
printf('task %s annotate -- ~/', GetUUID())
```

That returns a string with the UUID embedded between "task" and "annotate". In a Normal mode mapping that would be used like so:

```
:nnoremap <leader>X :<C-\>eprintf('task %s annotate -- ~/', GetUUID())<CR>
```

When executed you'll be on the command line with the cursor positioned after the `~/` so pressing tab will do file completion.

*<sub>Another way was suggested by @filbranden in the comments above (and filled out after this was posted). The method here is probably not as well known and perhaps a little more interesting as a result.</sub>

Comment: That works! Except I'm getting butt load of errors from the taskwiki plugin: https://pastebin.com/6AzKqTud Any ideas? It looks like an error from the GetUUID call but it pulls in the UUID just fine.

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: Here is the GUUID function: https://pastebin.com/H963i9zh

Comment: You can ignore the first 2 lines in that function. I still get the same error even with those lines commented out. It's just a dirty hack I'm using for updating the UUID.

Comment: I take that back. the dirty hack is the problem. I didn't reload the source like I thought.

Comment: So anyway, yeah, your solution worked. I need to find another dirty hack. :) Thanks!

Comment: Okay, cool. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Filbranden and D. Ben Knoble came up with something like

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>X printf(':!task %s annotate -- ~/', GetUUID())
```